# Modulo factoring of cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

The excercise is to factorize $\Phi_7$ into irreducible factors modulo $2$.

A theorem in my course: Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(q,n)=1$. Then the degree of every irreducible factor of $\Phi_n$ (mod $p$) in $\mathbb{F}_q$ is equal to the order of $q$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$.

I used this and concluded that $2\rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 = 1$ (mod $7$), so all the irreducible factors are of degree 3. Now the actual question. Given this knowledge how do I find the factorization? By trial and error I found
$$
X^6 + X^5 + X^4 + X^3 + X^2 + X + 1 = (X^3+X^2+1)(X^3+X+1) \text{ (mod $2$)}.
$$
Can someone help me to find this actual factorization systematically? That is for arbitrary $n$ and $q$, in which case trial and error won't work. Thank you!

---

Edit: Maybe my question is too greedy. If somebody could provide me with some insight on how to solve the factorization for very small numbers, that would already be a tremendous help.

Comment: Small numbers you say? A [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/131704/11619) has an example, but that is largely ad hoc. May be Berlekamp's factorization algorithm helps you in some other cases? An even smaller example is studied [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77155/11619). Note that unless you know the low degree irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{F}_2$ by heart, then the trick of going reciprocal helps in your case. Sorry that this is mostly just a bag of tricks.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially the first example using the frobenuis homomorphism is very useful.