# Splitting $\Phi_{15}$ in irreducible factors over $\mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: finite-fields, cyclotomic-polynomials

I have to split $\Phi_{15}$ in irreducible factors over the field $\mathbb{F}_7$. It has been a while that I did this kind of stuff, and to be the honest, I've never really understood this matter. I'd really be grateful if someone could show me how this works. I don't ask you to do this whole job. It would be better if I would get **some subtle advice** instead.

---

I use the following definition:
$$
\Phi_n(X) \quad = \quad \prod_{ord(\zeta) = n} (X - \zeta)
$$

Comment: Every such $\zeta$ can be written uniquely as $\zeta_1\zeta_2$ where $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_1)=3$ and $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_2)=5$. The cases where $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_1)=3$ are $2,4$.

Answer (score 7):

Consider that $x^3-1$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_7$ as:
$$ x^3-1 = (x-2)(x-1)(x+3) \tag{1}$$
while $x^5-1$ splits as:
$$ x^5-1 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1),\tag{2}$$
since the smallest field with characteristic $7$ in which there is a primitive fifth root of unity if $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}$, because $k=4$ is the first natural number such that $5\mid 7^k-1$.
For the same reason, the splitting field of $x^{15}-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$ is $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}$. Since $\deg \Phi_{15} = 8$, we have that $\Phi_{15}$ splits as the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree four over $\mathbb{F}_7$.

The key lemma is the following: if $x^l-1$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}_{7^a}$, then $l$ must divide $|\mathbb{F}_{7^a}^*|=7^a-1$ by the Lagrange's theorem. Since the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, this gives also a sufficient condition for $\mathbb{F}_{7^a}$ to be the splitting field of $x^l-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Back to the original question, how to recover the two factors of $\Phi_{15}$? Just look at the Jyrki Lahtonen's answer, that shows how the Frobenius automorphism of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^4}\simeq \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(q(x))$ gives that the roots of $q(x)$ are of the form $\xi,\xi^p,\xi^{p^2},\xi^{p^3}$.

Comment: I don't get the part where you say that $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}$ is the smallest field where we can find a root of unity. You say something about five dividing something but I don't see why that matters, where working in a field of char seven right?

Comment: If $x^l-1$ splits completely over $\mathbb{F}_{7^a}$, there must be an order-$l$ element in $\mathbb{F}_{7^a}^*$. By Lagrange's theorem, $l\mid(7^a-1)$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Answer (score 3):

Every such $\zeta$ can be written uniquely as $\zeta_1\zeta_2$ where $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_1)=3$ and $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_2)=5$. The cases where $\mathrm{ord}(\zeta_1)=3$ are $2,4$.

The $\zeta_2$ values are roots of $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=(x-\zeta_5)(x-\zeta_5^2)(x-\zeta_5^3)(x-\zeta_5^4)$. So 
$$\begin{align}(x-2\zeta_5)(x-2\zeta_5^2)(x-2\zeta_5^3)(x-2\zeta_5^4)& = 2^4+2^3x+2^2x^2+2x^3+x^4 \\&= 2+x+4x^2+2x^3+x^4\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}(x-4\zeta_5)(x-4\zeta_5^2)(x-4\zeta_5^3)(x-4\zeta_5^4)& = 4^4+4^3x+4^2x^2+4x^3+x^4 \\&= 4+x+2x^2+4x^3+x^4\end{align}$$

So, the products of these are $\Phi_{15}(x)$.

There are no roots for these, so the only possible factors can be quadratics.

The only possible option is: $(x-2\zeta_5)(x-2\zeta_5^4)=x^2-2(\zeta_5+\zeta_5^4)x+4$ and $(x-2\zeta_5^2)(x-2\zeta_5^3)$ for the first, and the related factoring for the second. But that only works if $\zeta_5+\zeta_5^4\in\mathbb F_7$, which we know algebraically requires $\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb F_7$, which is not the case. So:

$$\Phi_{15}(x)=(2+x+4x^2+2x^3+x^4)(4+x+2x^2+4x^3+x^4)$$

Comment: You sais that "the cases where $ord(\zeta_1)=3$ are $2,4$. Could you tell me what you mean by that?

Comment: It is the same as saying that the primitive third roots of unity in $\mathbb{F}_7$ are $2$ and $4$, or that $x^3-1$ splits completely as I wrote.

Comment: About the things you computed, I don't understand why there aren't any "-"-signs. I thought that if the number of zeros we multiply is odd, then a minus should appear. You understand what I mean?

Comment: $-3=4$ in $\mathbb F_7$. What you are saying might be true when dealing with integer polynomials, but not modular polynomials. @KoenraadvanDuin

Answer (score 2):

+1 to the question and both answers.

Koenraad, a different way of reaching the conclusion in Jack's answer is to use Galois theory. You hopefully remember that the Galois groups of finite fields are generated by the Frobenius map - in this case $F:a\mapsto a^7$. So if $\zeta$ is a fixed primitive fifteenth root of unity in whatever extension field $L$ of $K=\Bbb{F}_7$ it resides, its conjugates are
$$
\zeta^7,\quad \zeta^{49}=\zeta^{3\cdot15+4}=\zeta^4,\quad\zeta^{4\cdot7}=\zeta^{15+13}=\zeta^{13},\quad\zeta^{7\cdot13}=\zeta^{6\cdot15+1}=\zeta.
$$
So by iterating the Frobenius map we generated the listed four conjugates. Therefore the
polynomial
$$
p(x)=(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^7)(x-\zeta^4)(x-\zeta^{13})
$$
is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $K$. The nice trick in Thomas' answer is based on the observation that we can write these conjugates in the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\zeta&=\zeta^{10}\zeta^6\\
\zeta^7&=\zeta^{10}\zeta^{12}\\
\zeta^4&=\zeta^{10}\zeta^9\\
\zeta^{13}&=\zeta^{10}\zeta^3,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the recurring factor $\zeta^{10}$ on the right hand side is of order three (and can be identified as an element of $K$), and the other factors are exactly the roots of unity of order five.

---

Don't know if this helps. Ask, if you need more details.

Comment: Well thank you. Now I should check whether those roots belong to $\mathbb{F}_7$. That is, I have to discover whether $a(a-1) \in 15\mathbb{Z}$ if the root is equal to $\zeta^a$. And after that I should match those roots that don't belong to $\mathbb{F}_7$ in such a way that their products become irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_7[X]$. I don't see a nice way to do that, but I least I can do the first thing.

Comment: Galois theory tells you that the coefficients of $p(x)$ belong to $\Bbb{F}_7$, but the roots won't. Because there are four conjugates, they belong to $\Bbb{F}_{7^4}$ as Jack said. I think Thomas' method is the best for finding the actual factors. They are simply $2^{-4}\Phi_5(2x)$ and $4^{-4}\Phi_5(4x)$.

Comment: @Koenraad: My point is that we know immediately that none of the primitive roots belong to $\Bbb{F}_7$. For any element $z$ of $\Bbb{F}_7$ satisfied $z=z^7$. If $z$ is of order fifteen, then this is impossible.